# Form Builder in 4.3 Removing setvalue and help lines

Tags: orbeon

I have been using Form Builder to stage the deployment of Orbeon Forms.

Ie, I iterate form definitions between FB and Oxygen by copying the code into Form Builder -> Edit Source. Then I save and publish the form definition.

This seemed to work ok in 4.2 (ok - I would lose some comments, not ideal, but not functionality).
I'm now getting a very different situation using 4.3. Saving in Form Builder is removing actual code (not ideal). Has anyone else seen this?

For instance, my code:

```
        <xf:action id="create-job-binding">
            <!-- React to event... on control... -->
            <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="save-job-control" if="true()">
                <!-- Service to call -->
                <xf:send submission="new-job-submission"/>
            </xf:action>

            <!-- Request actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="new-job-submission">
                <!-- Get reference to initial request -->
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'new-job-instance'" as="xs:string"/>
                <!-- Copy over to read-write request instance -->
                <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                           origin="saxon:parse(instance($request-instance-name))"/>
                <!--<xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')" origin="instance($request-instance-name)"/>-->
                <!-- Set values if needed -->
                <xf:action context="instance('fr-service-request-instance')">
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <!-- Parameters -->
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'car-id'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/car-id" as="xs:string"/>
                        <!-- Set value -->
                        <xf:setvalue ref="$path" value="instance('edited-job')/job/*[name() = $control-name]"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <!-- Parameters -->
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'driver-id'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/driver-id" as="xs:string"/>
                        <!-- Set value -->
                        <xf:setvalue ref="$path" value="instance('edited-job')/job/*[name() = $control-name]"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <!-- Parameters -->
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'document'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/event-id" as="xs:string"/>
                        <!-- Set value -->
                        <xf:setvalue ref="$path"
                                     value="xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/*[name() = $control-name]"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <!-- Setvalue actions will be here -->
                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>
            <!-- Response actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="new-job-submission"
                       context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">
                <!-- Response actions will be here -->
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action> `
```

after saving in FB becomes:

```
         <xf:action id="create-job-binding">
            <!-- React to event... on control... -->
            <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="save-job-control" if="true()">
                <!-- Service to call -->
                <xf:send submission="new-job-submission"/>
            </xf:action>

            <!-- Request actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="new-job-submission">
                <!-- Get reference to initial request -->
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'new-job-instance'" as="xs:string"/>
                <!-- Copy over to read-write request instance -->
                <xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                           origin="saxon:parse(instance($request-instance-name))"/>
                <!--<xf:insert ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')" origin="instance($request-instance-name)"/>-->
                <!-- Set values if needed -->
                <xf:action context="instance('fr-service-request-instance')">
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'car-id'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/car-id" as="xs:string"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'driver-id'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/driver-id" as="xs:string"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
                        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'document'" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xf:var name="path" value="/request/event-id" as="xs:string"/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <!-- Setvalue actions will be here -->
                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>
            <!-- Response actions -->
            <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="new-job-submission"
                       context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">
                <!-- Response actions will be here -->
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action>
```

Notice loss of the setValue commands.

Also removed xf:help references:

```
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td colspan="2">
                                <xf:textarea id="pickup-address-control" bind="pickup-address-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/pickup-address/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/pickup-address/hint"/>

                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:textarea>
                            </xh:td>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:input id="pickup-postcode-control" bind="pickup-postcode-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/pickup-postcode/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/pickup-postcode/hint"/>

                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                            </xh:td>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:textarea id="notes-control" bind="notes-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/notes/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/notes/hint"/>

                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:textarea>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
```

Comment: UPDATE: The removal of the xf:help ref occurs when the referenced resource entry is an empty element, so maybe intended behaviour?

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, noticed [link](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/9f14be60576ffb1d76df88baf98b9a9c95281b29) to remove unnecessary help references. Wasn't expecting it to edit existing code, though.

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, the removal of the setvalue commands seems to be coming from the introduction of ~resources/apps/fr/components/actions.xsl. I had been using the Form Builder action template informally to update other instances. I need to go through and remove the class definitions on existing actions.

Comment: If you found an answer to your problem, do not change your question or change your title to “RESOLVED”; that doesn't mark it as answered in the UI. Instead, post your answer below. After a day or so you can mark it as the accepted answer, people who search for your question will see it has an answer, and you'll get a shiny new badge.

Comment: Jez, Where do you stand on this issue; have you found a solution? If you have, as @DourHighArch suggested, could you post the solution as an answer below? If not would you be able update your question with a full (but as-simple-as-possible, this instead of snippets) form source that shows the code removal you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be intended behaviour in 4.3 Form Builder/Runner. I maybe should have done a bit more research on 4.3 before posting. Anyway:

1. Removal of xf:help elements on controls. These are removed if the ref points to an empty element.
2. Removal of setvalue commands. These are removed if the class of the action is one which is templated in ~/resources/apps/fr/components/actions.xsl (for instance fr-set-control-value-action).

My 4.2 forms didn't work following upgrade because I had edited the source to change the action settings to refer to elements not within the FB context (other instances), but had left the class tag unchanged. Removal of the class tag solved the problem.